# software can't install properly

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, software-center

I installed eclipse on my Ubuntu 17.10. But after installing it doesn't show me in the installed software list and I'm also unable to add this to favourite list after installing. After closing this software it does not appear in the software list and when I need it I have to install it again.

There is no option to add as favourite:
[image: there is no option for add to favourite]

Comment: How did you install it?  If installed using Software Centre, Aptitude and like tools from packages it should show, however if installed from tarball etc. it's just files added to your filesystem and the packaging/menu system won't know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to reinstall it over an over again. You have to figure out where your **eclipse** executable file is, for example my eclipse binary is at:

```
/home/ubuntu/local/java-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse
```

Can you find a desktop icon for eclipse? If the installer is not creating one, you can create a **eclipse.desktop** on your desktop and write some content like the following (but with your own path to eclipse):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/home/ubuntu/local/java-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse %F
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/home/ubuntu/local/java-oxygen/eclipse/icon.xpm
Name[en_US]=eclipse
```

If you can find the `.desktop` file or you have created one, and you want the application to show up in any system menu, you can copy (or put) the `.desktop` file into one of the following directories:

```
/usr/share/applications
~/.local/share/applications
```

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: my eclipse executable file is(  /home/prabin/eclipse-workspace )   ............. now how can i create my .desktop file?

Comment: Nope, that's the workspace directory for java projects. Could you find a folder `/home/prabin/local/java-oxygen`?, you can run `locate java-oxygen` to locate the **java-oxygen** folder.

Comment: ( /home/prabin/Downloads/eclipse-java-oxygen-2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz )      locate java-oxygen shows this result.

Comment: and there is no local directory within prabin directory

Comment: **eclipse-java-oxygen-2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz** is the installation file. You could extract the file ( and an 'eclipse-installer' folder) should appear. Enter that folder in the terminal and you will see a file named **eclipse-inst**. You could install eclipse with command `./eclipse-inst`, but this time you have to memorize the folder you put the eclipse. Could you do that?